# Book recommendation on matrix differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation, matrix-calculus

As the title says, I am looking for a good reference on matrix differentiation.

I have already studied the content of Harville's contribution on the topic, but I would like to know if there are other good sources as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're just looking for differentiation rules for matrices you can look at the matrix cookbook. https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Could you also provide any theoretical book on the subject?